# How can I match regular expression with new lines and within brackets?

Tags: c#, regex

Here is an example of my text:

```
[10:24:33.361][RestApi.RestEngine  
ERROR GET 
process-meter/util/verify 
Status code Forbidden 
Content {"versions":1} 
]
```

The time portion:

```
[10:24:33.361]
```

was easy:

```
(\[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\])
```

What I need help with is the regular expression to match the string following the time, that is delimited by brackets, and has new lines in it

So I have edited this question to put it back to the "new lines" regular expression problem... and the solution is to re-write the logging object to put the output on a single line OR as Mike Robinson suggests, use a pre-parser, then use regular expressions.

Please mark this as closed.

Comment: I doubt you need [`\[(?>[^][]+|(?<o>)\[|(?<-o>)])*(?(o)(?!))]`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b(%3f%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%7c(%3f%3co%3e)%5c%5b%7c(%3f%3c-o%3e)%5d)*(%3f(o)(%3f!))%5d&i=%5b10%3a24%3a33.361%5d%5bRestApi.RestEngine++%0d%0aERROR%0d%0aGET+process-meter%2futil%2fverify%0d%0aStatus+code+Forbidden+%0d%0aContent+%7b%22versions%22%3a%5b1%5d%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a%5d), but try.

Comment: Based on your edits, which have substantively changed your question (and thus rendered all our answers useless, which, by the way, is against the "rules") because you've done away with the notion of multiple lines and based on your comment beneath my answer, I now have *no idea* what you're actually asking.  I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: @roryap Your answer does not really have to change after these changes. Your expression based on `[\S\s]*` will work the same way as `.*`.

Comment: You really have ignored my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All excellent answers, of course, but ... in addition ...*

"As you are strolling down this Primrose Path," please keep in mind two important things:

1. Some things simply can't be done using *just one* regular expression.
2. It is extremely easy to start by taking what ultimately turns out to be the *wrong* approach, and then to "tweak it and tweak it and tweak it again" as the actual file-data throws you one monkey-wrench after another.

In this case, I'd step-back and consider the general approach that has been taken by the `awk` utility, which first *classifies* the various lines in a file, then performs certain actions depending on what "type" of line was recognized. Even though the file in question appears to contain a "more nested," *vs.* "strictly line-by-line" structure, maybe you can get away with a line-by-line strategy this time.

To emulate this same logic in a tool other than `awk`, you would *first* use regular-expression to decide "what kind of source-line you have," then you'd invoke a subroutine specific to that kind of line.

But, finally, "sometimes you actually need a *parser."*

Comment: AGREED... or simply change the output of the log file to fit within the constraints of the Regular expression capabilities...

Answer (score 2):

Use `RegexOptions.MultiLine`

```
var match = Regex.Match("myInputStr", "my pattern", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Here's the documentation on what it does:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the beginning
    //     and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the
    //     entire string. For more information, see the "Multiline Mode" section in the
    //     Regular Expression Options topic.
    Multiline = 2,
```

Comment: This answer does not help OP at  all since OP patterns do not have neither `^` nor `$` anchors.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was under the impression that the OP was capable of editing the patterns

Comment: I am not capable of editing the patterns... or the code that calls the regular expression engine... I have a text box that I put the regular expression in, then the program performs it's magic and displays the output...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does the trick:

```
var pattern = @"(\[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}\])(\[[\s\S]*\])";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
var group = matches.Count > 0 ? matches[0].Groups[2] : null; // group == null if the input isn't a match for the pattern.
```

Here's `group.Value`:

```
[RestApi.RestEngine  
ERROR
GET process-meter/util/verify
Status code Forbidden 
Content {"versions":[1]}

]
```

Comment: This solution can help only in case the second `[...]` is the last `[...]` in the string. Also, there is no point using `[\s\S]` as there is an inline DOTALL modifier in .NET regex.

Comment: I can't edit the code.... all I have is a text box... so I changed my question a little bit... ( I can however alter the format of the log string and remove the new lines... the content however, remains the same)